# Broadcom wireless network card can't see any networks

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, fedora, broadcom

I have a fresh install of FC21 on a new box with a Broadcom wifi card. It took me a while but (I think) I finally have the right drivers installed (kmod-wl from rpmfusion) and NetworkManager is showing the wireless card. But when I try to select a network it says "No networks". I have a Netgear USB wireless adapter plugged in and that's working fine (detecting my home network and connecting fine).

I'm not really a guru when it comes to linux and hardware so stuck with what to try next.

Some info:

```
[andy@localhost ~]$ lspci | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)


[andy@localhost ~]$ lsmod | grep wl
wl                   6369280  0 
cfg80211              552960  1 wl


[andy@localhost ~]$ iwconfig
wlp0s18f2u4  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MySSID"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: A0:21:B7:9F:B2:2C   
      Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:124   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.


[andy@localhost ~]$ iwlist wlp2s0 scan
wlp2s0    No scan results
```

Selected output from dmesg with a couple of lines that look like errors:

```
[   10.008180] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   10.008185] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   10.013608] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   10.036352] eth0: Broadcom BCM43a0 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[   10.401050] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from eth0
[   17.512735] AMD-Vi: Event logged [INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST device=00:00.1 address=0x000000fdf80c0020 flags=0x0a00]
[  435.635168] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  435.635174] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
```

Comment: Is your module actually loaded? `lsmod | grep wl`

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, it is loaded. I have added output of lsmod to the question.